# Angular: how to bypass authentication when offline?

Tags: angularjs, html5-appcache, firebasesimplelogin

I'm writing an angular + firebase app, which supports user authentication via firebase-simple-login.
I need to make it usable when offline, too.

I'm using HTML5 AppCache for this (via grunt-manifest node helper module).

I suppose I will have to allow logon (of a cached user) without authentication when offline, and possibly request a regular logon when back online, to confirm firebase updates from user... Do you think this is an actionable strategy?

However, the final question is:

*Is it possible to bypass authentication when offline, and which is the strategy you'd suggest?*

Comment: This is really something that Fire base has to support, because really you're application code shouldn't change. You'll be making API calls but they won't hit Firebase, but just return AppCache data.

Comment: Of course it's a security hazard issue... Having your authentication info stored locally could be a problem... :-)